# Cancel the keydown in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, keydown

How can I cancel the `keydown` of a specific key on the keyboard, for example(space, enter and `arrows`) in an HTML page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're only interested in the example keys you mentioned, the `keydown` event will do, except for older, pre-Blink versions of Opera (up to and including version 12, at least) where you'll need to cancel the `keypress` event. It's much easier to reliably identify non-printable keys in the `keydown` event than the `keypress` event, so the following uses a variable to set in the `keydown` handler to tell the `keypress` handler whether or not to suppress the default behaviour.

**Example code using `addEventListener` and ignoring ancient version of Opera**

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
    // These days, you might want to use evt.key instead of keyCode
    if (/^(13|32|37|38|39|40)$/.test("" + evt.keyCode)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

**Original example code from 2010**

```
var cancelKeypress = false;

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    cancelKeypress = /^(13|32|37|38|39|40)$/.test("" + evt.keyCode);
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
    }
};

/* For pre-Blink Opera */
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: +1, I deleted my answer in favour of this one, I wasn't aware of the Opera issues :-)

Comment: Does Opera quirk still stand these days and times? You still need to cancel in keypress?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: I just tried it and it doesn't apply to the latest version of Opera. I would guess it doesn't apply to any Blink-based version of Opera.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to be sure as I'm writing come code that deals wit keydown cancellation and din't want to install Opera just to check this.

Comment: Note that if you alter the value of a textbox within the keydown event when pressing the up arrow, you'll have to use e.preventDefault() to prevent the cursor from appearing at the beginning of the text instead of the end of the text as intended. A very rare caveat, but is used for things such as web-based terminals when a user navigates through command history using the up & down arrow keys.

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: @EpicSpeedy Example? My guess would be that you're using `addEventListener("keydown")` rather than `onkeydown`, in which case you'll need to use `evt.preventDefault()` rather than `return false`.

Answer (score 5):

Catch the keydown event and return false. It should be in the lines of:

```
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e){
  var n = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(n==38 || n==40) return false;
}
</script>
```

([seen here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1262956&page=1))

The keycodes are defined [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx)

edit: update my answer to work in IE

Comment: `window.captureEvents` is obsolete and has been removed from newer versions of Firefox, and never supported by some other browsers.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.captureEvents.

Comment: @andy, @tim: true, I copied and pasted blindly. I corrected my answer. Of course now @tim's answer was the fastest and more accurate

Comment: preventDefault function works for me

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly very old thread.
In order to do the magic with IE10 and FireFox 29.0.1 you definitely must do this inside of `keypress` (not `keydown`) event listener function:

```
if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Works here.....

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice [KeyPress function](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) which allows you to detect a key press, then it should be just a case of detecting the keyvalue and performing an if for the ones you want to ignore.

edit:
for example:

```
$('#target').keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
     return false; // or event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: he's apaprently not using jquery based on the tags he set

Comment: i don't have a problem with using jquery beside that i'm using ASP.NET

Comment: @Luke: Does jQuery normalize the `keypress` event?  It behaves differently across browsers, so I would be interested to know if jQuery solves those differences.

Comment: @Andy E's Head: I am a great believer in all things jQuery, but I am no expert.  From what I have read, I'm pretty sure jQuery is cross browser, and according to their site supports IE6+ FF2+ Chrome and Safari.  If there are different behaviours for the keypress event, I am sure they have covered it.

Answer (score 0):

Just return false. Beware that on Opera this doesn't work. You might want to use onkeyup instead and check the last entered character and deal with it.
Or better of use JQuery KeyPress

Answer (score 0):

I only develop for IE because my works requires it, so there is my code for numeric field, not a beauty but works just fine

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[class='numeric-field']").keydown(function (e) {

        if (e.shiftKey == 1) {
            return false
        }

        var code = e.which;
        var key;

        key = String.fromCharCode(code);

        //Keyboard numbers   
        if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
            return key;
        } //Keypad numbers
        else if (code >= 96 && code <= 105) {
            return key
        } //Negative sign
        else if (code == 189 || code == 109) {
            var inputID = this.id;
            var position = document.getElementById(inputID).selectionStart
            if (position == 0) {
                return key
            }
            else {
                e.preventDefault()
            }
        }// Decimal point
        else if (code == 110 || code == 190) {
            var inputID = this.id;
            var position = document.getElementById(inputID).selectionStart

            if (position == 0) {
                e.preventDefault()
            }
            else {
                return key;
            }
        }// 37 (Left Arrow), 39 (Right Arrow), 8 (Backspace) , 46 (Delete), 36 (Home), 35 (End)
        else if (code == 37 || code == 39 || code == 8 || code == 46 || code == 35 || code == 36) {
            return key
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Upps, this wast not the numeric field blog, sorry