# How to simulate F1 pressed in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm developing a web solution to run in the clients existing portal. In this portal they already handle F1 differently from the default behaviour.

I would like to add a "Help" icon to my solution that when clicked simulates pressing F1. Of course I would like the solution to be as cross browser compatible as possible but the final version will run solely in Internet Explorer 8 (and actually with the compatibility button pressed - GRRRR).

I have found numerous functions to handle pressing F1 but non that describes how to simulate pressing F1 programmatically.

I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 if that helps...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason that they still run in IE8 (also with compatibility mode)? If I had a client that would run IE8 in compat. mode using the application I developed, I would require either a good browser that they use or that they drop this requirement.

Comment: The client has 25.000+ employees and are always quite late in updating their software. A lot of employees are still running XP(!). So it's out of my hands...

Comment: Ah ok, understandable :) I was just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to catch the event in IE:

- [Internet Explorer or any Browser F1 keypress displays your own help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405412/internet-explorer-or-any-browser-f1-keypress-displays-your-own-help)

and use these to fire the event:

- [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)
- http://openwritings.net/public/javascript/simulate-pressing-key

Comment: Using the example from openwritings I get an "undefined method" when calling dispatchEvent...

Answer (score 0):

On this page https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys#readme there is this quote:
*"Others, (IE) either let you handle built-in short-cuts, but will add their functionality after your code has executed. Or (Opera/Safari) will not pass those events to the DOM at all.
So, if you bind Ctrl-Q or Alt-F4 and your Safari/Opera window is closed don't be surprised."*

Which means that you probably can't do what you want to do, as pressing F1 will launch the help from Windows.

Comment: Well the portal for which I'm developing a frame already handles this but that's when pressing F1 on the keyboard. I want to click an icon and simulate pressing F1.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 112 });
```

Comment: Hmm... can't get this to work. Trying in Chrome where I normally get a new help tab. This does nothing. Same in IE.

Comment: huh, I'm pretty sure that this is the correct keycode. may if you trigger `keyup` instead?

Comment: Nope :-( Nothing. In Chrome when I press F1 I get a new tab with Chrome help. Clicking a link executing the code above (or with keyup) does nothing :-( I'll have to figure something else out. Thanks for the effort everyone.