# Opera preventDefault() on keydown event

Tags: javascript, linux, opera, keyevent, preventdefault

I'm trying to embed some keybindings in my webapp, and I'm having hard times with Opera. I have this code:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode ? e.charCode : false;
  if (e.ctrlKey && key === 84) {
    alert("foo");
    e.preventDefault();
    // return false;
  }
}
```

It works like a charm in Firefox and Chrome, but Opera still opens new tab. Same happens with `return false;`.

My info: `Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; en) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.00`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Opera [doesn't support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t09) `preventDefault` on `keydown`, only on `keypress`.

As you can see in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036243/cancel-the-keydown-in-html/3036385#3036385), you should bind a separate `keypress` handler for Opera (adapted to your situation):

```
var cancelKeypress = false;

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    cancelKeypress = (evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 84);
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
    }
};

/* For Opera */
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: @hallvors: You're welcome, but eh... what bug are you sorry about? Do you work for Opera?

Comment: Yes, I do :). This is one of the most common problems that trip up web developers and we should finally get aligned with other browsers before the next major release.

Comment: @hallvors: Ah, yes, I see now. Nice to have someone of Opera around here. BTW, [that](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/why-twitter-doesnt-count) is indeed a horrible browser sniffing decision of Twitter, especially as they are using jQuery (and yes, I see the difference between `input` and `textInput`).

Comment: @hallvors: Just one more question: how are we going to detect it when Opera doesn't have this bug anymore? Detect the browser version with feature inference, like [shown here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/jsexamples/sniffer.html)? There's even a [nice page](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/specs/) that exactly describes which functions are supported. ;-)

Comment: you saved my life