# keydown with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I am not sure how to do 'keydown' with pure JavaScript.

Here's how I did it with jQuery, but is there a way to do the same thing with pure JS also ?
I just wanna check if there is a way and to learn how to do it, as well as to see difference and length of code. Thank you.

```
$('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) return false;
});
```

EDIT: It is used to disable "Esc" button!

Comment: Did you not search "keydown JavaScript" in your favorite search engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036243/cancel-the-keydown-in-html

Comment: I did search indeed @epascarello. However none works. If I add alert or console log it works but if I wanna override something that has "close" on Esc press it wont work. Works with jQuery tho :/

Comment: Have fun with the cross browser issues in pure javascript - you know you CAN look at the jQuery source code to see how  it is done there also...just sayin as that is exactly what you appear to be asking.

Comment: Why don't you show what does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like setting the listeners as attributes, so I add even listeners like this:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('test');
ele.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    //code
}, false);
```

Comment: IE8 and under do not support addEventListener

Comment: Why I can't get any of answers to work ! 
They all work but on random thing that I put such as alert(); but not for overriding fancybox esc closure! :(

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) return false;
}
```

As you can see jQuery is shorter but this will execute less code

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<body onkeydown="YourFunction(event)">...</body>
```

**JS**

```
function YourFunction(e)
{
     var unicode=e.keyCode || e.charCode|| e.which;
     if(unicode == 27)
        return false;
     else
     {
        //Your code...
     } 
}
```

Comment: IE does not pass in the event object.

Comment: hmmm.. I'm using IE9.0. There it's working fine. and also i changed the Browser Mode as **IE7 & IE8**. There also this code working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript it is done this way

```
document.body.onkeydown=function(e){
  key=e.keyCode || e.charCode|| e.which; //cross browser complications
  if(key===27){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Hope it helped, it is the same script as the JQuery one you provided

Comment: Updated and now, I it'll have a little better browser support, Not sure about IE though