# Restrict characters in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is there a way to block users from writing specific characters in input fields? I tried the code below, but when a user enters disallowed characters, they appear for a brief period before disappearing. I want the input to remain unchanged when invalid characters are written.

I want to use `onchange` because other restriction methods do not seem to work on mobile devices. The problem I want to solve is that characters appear briefly before being removed.

```js
function checkInput(ob) {
  const invalidChars = /[^0-9]/gi;

  if(invalidChars.test(ob.value)) {
    ob.value = ob.value.replace(invalidChars, "");
  }
};
```

```html
<input class="input" maxlength="1" onChange="checkInput(this)" onKeyup="checkInput(this)" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: why not set type='password'....

Comment: also it should be type="input" not class="input" anyway. (and if you want to style it, use [type="input"])

Comment: @iJay OP doesn't want to hide all characters but remove some of them.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo he want to hide them.

Comment: You could use html5 "pattern" attribute to enforce a regex

Comment: Same things does if i set to password and i try to use letters or other characters except numbers. + when is set to password it doesnt show me the number,it does show a bullet

Comment: can you change the script???

Comment: just call function on "onkeypress" event

Comment: why you using two event listeners in you html?

Comment: The problem is that i have tryed already differet restrict characters code but this one works for tablets too.The only thing is that when i type restricted characters it show em for a second and i need to do not display them at all

Comment: @CJRamki because onchange i have another code

Comment: `maxlength="1"` ? you just want only one character in text box?

Comment: @CJRamki yes,just 1 character in input fields (6) and ONLY number.Other characters shouldnt be able to appear at all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel the keydown in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036243/cancel-the-keydown-in-html)

Comment: @mplungjan nope,this is a problem with different question

Comment: Why dont color your text the same as your background? if there is a delay they wont see it anyway.

Comment: @UglyEddie i was thinking of doing that but is nasty ..should be an answer with js/jquery code that will do that

Comment: @user3459377 in what way different. If you intercept the keydown, you will not see the char in the field

Comment: @user3459377 Check my answer, I guess this is what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 restricting input characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607278/html5-restricting-input-characters)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use try this,

```
$('.input').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/[0-9]/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/2wGpq/)**</kbd>

**Updated :**

You can try this Code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape and enter
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/995193/2567813)</kbd>

<kbd>**[SEE UPDATED FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/PVs4S/)**</kbd>

**UPDATED FOR ANDROID:**

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:inputType="number"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
android:maxLength="1" >
</EditText>
```

I think it may help you... using `android:inputType="number"` you can do that.

Comment: Same delay when i try to use restricted chars in input

Comment: How did this get two upvotes when it doesn't even work?

Comment: @Niklas If you open the fiddle and type a,b,c,d ... you could see a delay there,letters are shown for a second,try to keep a letter pressed too

Comment: Yap it does.Thank you CJRamki

Comment: 1 more thing,sholdnt allow .

Comment: Done,now works great.But do you know if works for android platforms too?

Comment: Is there a reason you allow the up arrow (38), but not down arrow (40)? I used `e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40` for my case.

Comment: The first snippet does not work with pasting/drag&drop, and the latter does not work with non-QWERTY keyboard layouts. I think it's better to [use the `beforeinput` event to reject invalid inputs beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549391).

Answer (score 10):

A combination of keypress and paste events does a trick:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
text.onkeypress = text.onpaste = checkInput;

function checkInput(e) {
    var e = e || event;
    var char = e.type == 'keypress' 
        ? String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which) 
        : (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
    if (/[^\d]/gi.test(char)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input class="input" maxlength="10" id="text" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

This code prevents from typing or pasting anything but a number. Also no blinking and invalid characters don't show up.

Works in IE7+.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VgtTc/3/

Comment: This code does not work with drag&drop, `e.keyCode` and `e.which` are deprecated, and `return false` should probably be `e.preventDefault()`. I think the modern approach is to [handle the `beforeinput` event to reject invalid inputs in a generic way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549391/).

Answer (score 10):

All answers given so far suffer from at least one of the following **accessibility** issues:

1. They validate key codes, which does not work with non-QWERTY keyboard layouts.
2. They do not cover all input methods; especially drag&drop is often forgotten.
3. They alter the `value`, which resets the position of the caret.
4. They use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute, but this does not provide feedback until the form is submitted.

Wouldn't it be a much better idea to actually **validate the input before it's inserted**?

---

The [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) event fires *before* the input's value is changed. The event has a `data` property which describes the content that the user wants to add to the input field. In the event handler, you simply check the `data` attribute, and stop the event chain if it contains disallowed characters.

We end up with the following very simple, very short code.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$");

input.addEventListener("beforeinput", (event) => {
  if (event.data != null && !regex.test(event.data)) 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<label for="input">Enter some digits:</label>
<input id="input" />
```

---

Some closing notes:

- **Accessibility:** Provide a clear explanation of what input format is expected from the user. For example, you can use the [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#title) of the input to show a tooltip explaining the expected format.
- **Security:** This is [client-side validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#client-side_validation), and does not guarantee that the pattern is enforced when the form is sent to a server. For that, you'll need server-side validation.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It doesn't rely on any hacks and correctly intercepts the potential value before it actually changes in the `<input>` element. It also shows how you can use a variable or other object attribute to control the regex of allowed characters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little hack you could try: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sRTyx/6/)

What it does is that it colors every input text white and then changes it back to black if it suits your requirements. If you could live with the bit of lag that occurs when you enter a valid character.

```
function checkInput(ob) {
    var invalidChars = /[^0-9]/gi
    if (invalidChars.test(ob.value)) {
        ob.value = ob.value.replace(invalidChars, "");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('yourinput').style.color = '#000';
    }
};

function hideInput(ob) {
    document.getElementById('yourinput').style.color = '#FFF';
};
```

html

```
<input id="yourinput" class="input" maxlength="1" onKeydown="hideInput(this)" onKeyup="checkInput(this)" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

css

```
input {color:#FFF;}
```

Comment: Aint any way of doing that without useing css? Its just a delay when you press restricted characters that i dont want to be displayed at all

Comment: Ur answer is good,as you said its a little hack but i still wonder how can i use this code without delay

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying some other things but I can't seem to get rid of the lag.

Answer (score 1):

check this code,

```
$('.input').keypress(function(e) {
    var a = [];
    var k = e.which;

    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
        a.push(i);

    if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="testInput"></input>

<script>
testInput.onchange = testInput.oninput = restrict;

function restrict() {
    testInput.value = testInput.value.replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
}
</script>
```

I came up with something slightly different. oninput instead of onkeyup/onkeydown, and onchange instead of onpaste.

Comment: Note that this resets the caret every time an invalid input is entered, which is annoying for the user if they want to edit the start of the input and press the wrong key. [You can use the `beforeinput` event to reject invalid inputs before they're even inserted.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549391)

Answer (score 0):

I restrict invalid characters on both keypress and paste events like:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="validateKey(event)" onpaste="validatePaste(this, event)">
```

And define functions to handle these events inside  tab or a separate javascript file:

```
<script>
function validateKey(e) {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 8,9,13,37,39:
      break;
    default:
      var regex = /[a-z .'-]/gi;
      var key = e.key;
      if(!regex.test(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      break;
  }
}
function validatePaste(el, e) {
  var regex = /^[a-z .'-]+$/gi;
  var key = e.clipboardData.getData('text')
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```