# How to cancel onkeydown for accent mark

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to make an input text that only write `\[A-Za-z0-9 -]\` so i put the condition in onkeydown function. It works well. Almost. If you write `ẃéŕýúíó` (something with accent mark) it doesn't work.

Extreme case:

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="return false;"/>
```

I can write `á`. How to prevent it?

Edit:

Code with `\[A-Za-z0-9 -]\`

```js
const verif = (event) => {
  const char = event.key
  if(char!=="Unidentified"){// when á return Unidentified
    return /[A-Za-z0-9 -]/.test(char)
  }else{
    console.log("why!!")
    return false
  }
}
//tested on chrome 72
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="return verif(event);" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict characters in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708434/restrict-characters-in-input-field)

Comment: If you use html5 you can use `<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+">`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery            Please scroll down and look to all possible answers

Comment: @RomainB. I just tried this in a Codepen, and it prevents absolutely nothing :/ I can type every accented character I want in the input field

Comment: Can you share the code where you tried with `[A-Za-z0-9 -]` regex?

Comment: @JeremyThille IIRC it validates on submit

Comment: but that's not OP's requirement. OP wants to prevent accented characters input, not allow them then validate them afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 restricting input characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607278/html5-restricting-input-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event to get changes when the user is typing inside of the field.

```js
$('#test').on('input',(e)=>{
 let newValue = e.currentTarget.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, '')
  e.currentTarget.value = newValue
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text" placeholder="test"/>
```