# How to restrict input to not able input char #

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restrict html input, so user cannot input char # into the input

i tried to use pattern but it seems not working

i add these pattern to my input pattern="[^-#]+"

i expect the user cannot input char #, but it still can, what was wrong?

Comment: This answer should help you. [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22708940/3048967)

Comment: `pattern` won't stop users from typing in those characters. You'd have to use keyup event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict characters in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708434/restrict-characters-in-input-field)

Comment: possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key up event and use `replace()` to replace `#` with empty string `''`.

```html
<script>
function validateInput()
{
   var data = document.getElementById("input").value;
   data = data.replace('#','');
   document.getElementById("input").value = data;
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="validateInput()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Place your logic in `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` event handler function. find out the `charCode`. It must be 35. Then simply `event.preventDefault()` if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

use `replace` `function` to replace # with space on `keyup` or `oninput` event.

```html
<input type="text" 
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/#/g, '')" />
```